# Изменение ширины блока в зависимости от высоты другого

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. подскажите, как сделать такую верстку, где ширина блока зависит от высоты другого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е.если высота блока 1 меньше высоты блока 2, тогда блок 3 на всю ширину, иначе блок 3 имеет туже ширину, что и блок 2, а блок 1 просто опускается вниз (как в обычном 2-колоночном дизайне)

Желательно подскажите решение на css.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, думаю должно помочь https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2QGemSlOes

Comment: @Дмытрык  У меня не стоит задача выровнять блоки по высоте. На js, как я вижу - проверить высоту блока 1 и блока 2, если блок 1 выше, то добавляем какой-то класс в body. И в зависимости от наличия класса - разная ширина блоков....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант CSS. высота "блока 1" влияет на отображение ширины (блока 2,3)

```css
.b1 {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  height: 30px
}

.b2 DIV {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff0000
}

.b3 DIV {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00ff00
}
```

```html
   <div class="b1">блок 1</div>
<div class="b2">
  <div>блок 2</div>
</div>
<div class="b3">
  <div>блок 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а есть какие-нибудь подводные камни использования этого решения?

Comment: @Alex даже не знаю. если найдёте скиньте сюда коментом. А так вроде для решения поставленной задачи пример работает. Можете прогнать через валидатор W3C